# Can't retrieve select option from php script?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have one form which on submit sends data to external .php script. I want to disable possibility of inserting 2 students with same name into database. So if input was invalid, I want that inputed fields in form have last inputed values. I solved that, but i don't know how to retrieve last selected options? This is my code:

```
<form action="student.php" name="add-student" method="post" onSubmit="return Validate()">
Firstname:<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php  if(isset($_GET['firstname'])){echo $_GET['firstname'];}

Degree:<select name="degree" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['degree'])){echo '<option value=$_GET[["degree"]></option>';} ?>"> **//This is what i can't solve!!!**
<option value="1">First degree</option>
<option value="2">Second degree</option>
<option value="3">Third degree</option>
</select>
</form>
```

My external php script:

```
<?php
$firtsname=$_POST['firstname'];
$degree=$_POST['degree'];

$duplicate=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student WHERE firstname='$firstname'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($duplicate)>0)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($duplicate);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("Name already exists in db.")';
echo '</script>'; 
echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://localhost/administrator.php?firstname=".$firstname."&degree=".$degree."'); </script>";
}
else{
$sql="INSERT INTO student (firstname,degree) VALUES('$firstname','$degree')";
?>
```

Comment: You want last inserted value ?

Comment: if input vas invalid, i want my last input stays in field, and my last selected option stays as it was. i'm working on a project which has large form with 10 input fields and 2 selects, so if my input is invalid, i want to keep last inputed values, so i don't need to type it again...

Comment: can you show us Validate() function ?

Comment: no need to show it, it's simple, it doesn't allow to send data from form to script if firstname is empty...

Comment: @IvanPandžić - it's not about if the firstname is empty or not, it's about not inserting duplicates.

Comment: i check duplicate entries with this line:
$duplicate=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student WHERE firstname='$firstname'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($duplicate)>0)...

and with validate() function checks only that firtsname isn't empty

Comment: @IvanPandžić aah ok - look at my answer for another approach :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, thank you all for help anyway, it should look like this:

```
Degree:<select name="degree">
<option value="1" <?php if($_GET['degree']=='1') {?> selected="selected" <?php }; ?> >First degree</option>
<option value="2" <?php if($_GET['degree']=='2') {?> selected="selected" <?php }; ?> >Second degree degree</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
   Degree:<select name="degree" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['degree'])){echo '<option
    value='".$_GET["degree"]."' selected></option>';} ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect use of input and dropdown forms together. Try this

```
<form action="student.php" name="add-student" method="post" onSubmit="return Validate()">
Firstname:<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php  if(isset($_GET['firstname'])){echo $_GET['firstname'];}?>">
</form>
Degree:<select name="degree"> 
<option value="<?php if(isset($_GET['degree'])){echo $_GET["degree"];}?>"></option>
<option value="1">First degree</option>
<option value="2">Second degree</option>
<option value="3">Third degree</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes-problem. This line

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['degree'])){echo '<option value=$_GET[["degree"]></option>';} ?>
```

should be -

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['degree'])){ $v = $_GET['degree']; echo '<option value="$v"></option>';} ?>
```

**Note**

- You can access variables within double quotes (`"$foo"`).
- You can't access variables within single quote ('`$foo`'). It will be a string with value $foo. (`'$foo'=="\$foo"`).

**Update** - Your markup is malformed.

```
<select name="degree" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['degree'])){echo '<option value=$_GET[["degree"]></option>';} ?>">
```

Would actually print something like -

```
<select name="degree" value="<option value=x</option>"> <!-- Wrong! -->
```

Try this -

```
    <select name="degree">
    <?php if(isset($_GET['degree'])){$deg = $_GET["degree"]; echo "<option selected="selected" value=\"$deg\"></option>";} ?>">
```

Comment: i don't know why, but still it's not working, when i get redirected back to my form, option degree is set to default value=1...:/

Comment: i have inserted now select="selected" in this line, but again, nothing

Comment: @IvanPandžić Have you read the update in my answer? Your markup is malformed. Fix that. And its not `select="selected"`, it is `selected="selected"`

Comment: won't work again. now ,when it redirects me to my form, there is 4th option which is selected but, it's blank...

Comment: value=$_GET[["degree"] would set the value to string $_GET[["degree"] and not the actual value. There is also one bracket to much.

Comment: Still same issue. I would change value="$deg" to value='" . $deg . '" because of echo is starting with '. If you want to do your approach you would have to use echo "... and escape quotes with backslashes, like select=\"selected\" value="$deg"

Answer (score 0):

When the database are able to work, let it do the work. In your case you use PHP to much of the actual database-operations.

1. Make sure that the column firstname in the database has a key set to unique.
2. Use parameters in queries (for avoiding sql-injection)

I would do something like this: (i have NOT tested)

```
<?php
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$degree=$_POST['degree'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO student (firstname,degree) VALUES(?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($firstname, $degree);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$lastInsertID = $stmt->insert_id;

//lastInsertID would be 0 if no execution of INSERT has been made (based on the IGNORE keyword)
if($lastInsertID == 0)  
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Name already exists in db.")';
    echo '</script>'; 
    echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://localhost/administrator.php?firstname=".$firstname."&degree=".$degree."'); </script>";
}

?>
```

To solve your problem about retrieving the options when incorrect, change your lines to:

```
Firstname:<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['firstname'])){echo $_GET['firstname'];}?> " />
Degree:<select name="degree" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['degree'])){echo '<option value="' . $_GET["degree"] . '"></option>';} ?>">
```

Also change your redirection to:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.assign('http://localhost/administrator.php?firstname='.$firstname.'&degree='.$degree); </script>";
```

Comment: i'm going crazy, none of this isn't workin, thank you all for your help, but it looks like i'm gonna need some instructions...

Comment: See my last edit (I've missed an important quotation mark). What is happening then? Error?

Comment: hm $firtsname should be $firstname. I've changed it.

Comment: it won't work with POST anyway...because(i'm new with php so excuse me if i'm wrong), i send data firstname and degree back to te form page in addres bar with this line:
echo "<script>window.location.assign('http://localhost/administrator.php?firstname=".$firstname."&degree=".$degree."'); </script>";
so i read this vars with $_GET...

Comment: aha.. ok then it should be $_GET. Please forgive me, i missed that... I will edit.